# Finding longest overlapping interval pair

Tags: algorithm, intervals, overlap, schedule

Say I have a list of *n* integral intervals [a,b] each representing set S = {a, a+1, ...b}. An overlap is defined as |S_1 \cap S_2|. Example: [3,6] and [5,9] overlap on [5,6] so the length of that is 2. The task is to find two intervals with the longest overlap in Little-O(n^2) using just recursion and *not* dynamic programming.

Naive approach is obviously brute force, which does not hold with time complexity condition. I was also unsuccessful trying sweep line algo and/or Longest common subsequence algorithm.

I just cannot find a way of dividing it into subproblems. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Also found this, which in my opinion does not work at all:

[Finding “maximum” overlapping interval pair in O(nlog(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312714/finding-maximum-overlapping-interval-pair-in-onlogn)

Comment: If the question is about finding an algorithm and not about implementing it, perhaps [cs.se] would suit better? (but remember [don't crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and read their help center before asking)

Comment: Just saying "in my opinion does not work at all" does not justify that it doesn't actually work. You need to *explain* why it doesn't work and why your question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Brute force would run in O(n^2) so it should meet the problem requirements

Comment: @Mitchel0022 please see the difference between Little-O and Big-O notation

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that takes `N log(N)` time.

Breakdown every interval `[a,b] [c,d]` into an array of pair like this:

```
pair<a,-1>
pair<b,a>
pair<c,-1>
pair<d,c>

sort these pairs in increasing order. Since interval starts are marked as -1, in case of ties interval they should come ahead of interval ends.

for i = 0 to end of the pair array
    if current pair represents interval start
        put it in a multiset
    else
        remove the interval start corresponding to this interval end from the multiset.
        if the multiset is not empty
            update the maxOverlap with (current_interval_end - max(minimum_value_in_multiset,start_value_of_current_interval)+1)
```

This approach should update the `maxOverlap` to the highest possible value.

Answer (score 0):

Keep info about the two largest overlapping intervals `max1` and `max2` (empty in the beginning).

Sort the input list `[x1, y1] .. [xn, yn]` = `I1..In` by the value `x`, discarding the shorter of two intervals if equality is encountered. While throwing intervals out, keep `max1` and `max2` updated.

For each interval, add an attribute `max` in linear time, showing the largest `y` value of all preceding intervals (in sorted list):

```
rollmax = −∞
for j = 1..n do
  Ij.max = rollmax
  rollmax = max(rollmax, Ij.y)
```

On sorted, filtered, and expanded input list perform the following query. It uses an ever expanding sublist of intervals smaller then currently searched for interval `Ii` as input into recursive function `SearchOverlap`.

```
for i = 2..n do
  SearchOverlap(Ii, 1, i − 1)
return {max1, max2}
```

Function `SearchOverlap` uses `divide and conquer` approach to traverse the sorted list `Il, .. Ir`. It imagines such list as a complete binary tree, with interval `Ic` as its local root. The test `Ic.max < I.max` is used to always decide to traverse the binary tree (go left/right) in direction of interval with largest overlap with `I`. Note, that `I` is the queried for interval, which is compared to `log(n)` other intervals. Also note, that the largest possible overlapping interval might be passed in such traversal, hence the check for largest overlap in the beginning of function `SearchOverlap`.

```
SearchOverlap(I , l, r)
c = ceil(Avg(l, r)) // Central element of queried list
if Overlap(max1, max2) < Overlap(I , Ic) then
  max1 = I
  max2 = Ic
if l ≥ r then
  return
if Ic.max < I.max then
  SearchOverlap(I , c + 1, r)
else
  SearchOverlap(I , l, c − 1)
return
```

Largest overlapping intervals (if not empty) are returned at the end. Total complexity is `O(n log(n))`.